# Vectors in Java - Yahtzee Game

Tags: java, variables, vector, boolean, constants

I've been asked to program a Yahtzee game on Java. The thing is, I've got a vector of 5 values (which represent dice) and the values are randomly generated with this code:

```
Value= 1 + (int)(Math.random() * (5.999))
```

Now, the problem is that once the numbers are generated (or the dice have been thrown), the player is allowed to choose some of the values and hold them (make them constant), so then when the new values are generated, the ones selected don't change.

I've been trying to do this with a boolean variable, but with no luck. What would be the way to keep the values of a vector constant? I'd really appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: You can multiply by `6`.  Vector was replaced by ArrayList in 1998. You keep values of Vector constant by not changing them.  Can you clarify why you are changing the Vector at all (if you don't want to change it)?

Comment: Any reason to not use a standard array if there's always 5 dice?

Comment: Also, don't use the complicated expression. Just use `Random#nextInt()`.

Comment: In the game, the player can throw the dices 3 times in 1 turn. The objective is to get all the dices to be the same, so you can choose what dices to hold, and throw the other ones again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a `List<Integer>`. Remove any values the player does not keep and then fill it back to size 5 at next throw.

Another way would be making a `Dice` class with `randomize()` and `hold()` methods, and have `randomize()` generate a new random value only if `hold()` has not been called.

Comment: Thanks! I have a `Dice` class like you say. Made the `hold()` method and it's working fine now, only generates the values that are not hold.